# Data stream between stream analytics services and WebApp service (.NET core 3.1)

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-stream-analytics

I and my team are trying to build an app for data visualization and analysis in WebApp the data source is from Stream Analytics Services,
    can we connect to Stream Analytics from .NET core web app, if there is any way please provide reference resources.
    what is the best practice or service to use for data stream if I am using WebApp?
    Or can we connect to IOTHub from WebApp, which is a better option compared with the above one?

Thank you, Ranjith

Comment: HI Ranjith, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Azure Stream Analytics cannot stream data directly into a .Net core web app.

**Option1:** You can visualize data from your Azure IoT Hub in a web application.

**Option2:** If you want to use Azure Stream Analytics, you need to send the data into supported outputs and then connect to the Web app.

[image]

**Reference:**

[Visualize real-time sensor data from your Azure IoT hub in a web application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-live-data-visualization-in-web-apps)

[Creating a simple IoT application using a RaspberryPi+ NET Core and Azure](https://www.ipointsystems.com/blog/2018/august/creating-a-simple-iot-application-using-a-raspberrypi-net-core-and-azure)